# CSV import works in Numbers, but fails in Mac Excel and Mac OpenOffice Calc

Tags: ms-office, numbers, open-office

If I open a CSV file in Numbers, a particularly long series of text-only cells works like a charm.

If I open the same CSV file in Microsoft Excel for Mac, or OpenOffice Calc for Mac, the long cells break, though at different points.

*Quick Look* shows me that the CSV file is proper and complete.

The issue seems to occur when a row hits 2^16-1 characters — roughly the length of a `TEXT` block.

Here are some images, cropped for privacy:

A view of the source CSV:

[image: A view of the source CSV]

The working Numbers application:

[image: The working Numbers application]

The failing Calc application: (note that the selected cell is empty, though it contains the text "NULL" in the source CSV)

[image: The failing Calc application]

Since Apple does this well, I have no work-stopping issue with this. I'm curious about what makes Apple does this well while competitors fall down.

**What system feature allows MacOS do this particular task better than competitors?**

I ask this question partly out of curiosity, but more out of a wish to improve my office efficiency in the near future. I believe that a better understanding of the MacOS system may help this project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to edit your question to remove the "why does Apple..." as no one knows why Apple does anything and such questions are off topic. Stick to a technical question and you'll be fine here.

Comment: @SteveChambers I agree with you about Apple's mysteries, and I appreciate the tongue-in-cheek nature of the comment. :-) It does remain a fact, however, that "I'm curious why Apple does this well while competitors fall down." My question was and remains in boldface. Still, I think your comment exhibits wisdom. I'm editing the question. Thanks for the good advice.